# GWT TabLayoutPanel using cssresources

Tags: css, gwt, gwt-tablayoutpanel

I would like to style the tab bar element of the  TabLayoutPanel using the Cssresources mechanism.

According to the documentation here is the style rule for accessing the bar : 
.gwt-TabLayoutPanel .gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabs
the tab bar element

I can set the style for the entire panel but how do I set the style for the TabLayoutPanelTabs  property using Cssresources ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the ClientBundle feature of GWT.

Someone posted a solution that seems to address your problem. Check out: [GWT Vertical Tabs like iGoogle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810876/gwt-vertical-tabs-like-igoogle), particularly the "lightweight" solution answer. It explains how to overload CSS for individual tabs and make them available via an interface.